# Rails: f.association and clickable Image

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am attempting to make a checkbox list that instead of words has clickable images.  I have been successful in converting a multi-select list to clickable images that submit to a database -- but unsuccessful in getting them to associate to the table so when the form is called back it shows the selected items.

I was thinking that this may work in terms of using a check box list:

```
<%= f.association :attitudes, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Attitude.all, :label => false, :label_method => lambda { |img_url| "#{img_url.img_url}, #{img_url.id}".html_safe }%>
```

img_url is a field in Attitude that contains the image.  Unfortunately any combination I use does not return the image.  At best I get the field in text format.  Does anyone know if this can be done and if not is there another way to pull down a list of associated images from a database that I could turn into clickable images.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like

```
<%= f.association :attitudes, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Attitude.all, :label => false, :label_method => lambda { |img_url| "#{image_tag(img_url.img.url)}, #{img_url.id}".html_safe }%>
```